# Why is this div not inheriting the correct width style

Tags: css, width

My .left div has it's width set to 260px in the CSS but for some reason it's computed style is coming out at 980px (the full width of the wrapper) and is therefore pushing out another fiv (div right) on the page. Site is [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite) and the section I'm talking about is the left h2's and the right paragraph text in the 'who am i?' section.

**HTML**

```
<div id="topwrapper">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>I create films <span class="green">//</span></h2>
        <h2>I dance <span class="green">//</span></h2>
        <h2>I do silly things <span class="green">//</span></h2>
        <h2>I explore <span class="green">//</span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>lorem ipsum (changed as text is wordy)</p>
         <p>lorem ipsum (changed as text is wordy)</p>
         <p>lorem ipsum (changed as text is wordy)</p>

      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
width:250px;
float:left;
text-align:right;
padding-right:50px;
}

.right {
    float:right;
    width:680px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you included that CSS? I don't see it. Yeah.. that CSS definitely isn't being loaded.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar is right; that CSS is not on the site. Adding it in makes it work.

Comment: @irrelephant I posted as an answer so you can mark it correct.

Comment: Any help as to why it isn't being loaded? It's linked correctly in the file, and the file is definitely working as I can access it fine on www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/content.css

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you included that CSS? I don't see it. Yeah.. that CSS definitely isn't being loaded.

Comment: I'm double checking now, really confused as it's in the headers correctly, and a lot of the CSS in the file (content.css) seems to be working. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll keep hunting to see why it's not working!

Comment: This is weird... I don't know o_o

Comment: @Francesca there is an extra `}` above the `.left` block.

Comment: Ah yes thank you! So it was being loaded but was one little character throwing it off. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the bad markup.  // is not how you comment out html.  The html comment looks like:

```
<!-- </span></h2>  -->
```

when you have bad markup the browser does funny things to match up mismatched elements such as those span elements that are "commented out".

Just my initial thought.  I'll keep looking though.

I used the javascript editor at http://w3schools.com and it worked for me.  I like to edit my code at that website.
This is the code I used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.left {
width:250px;
float:left;
text-align:right;
padding-right:40px;
border:1px solid blue;
}

.right {
    float:right;
    width:250px;
border:1px solid green;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="topwrapper">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>I create films <span class="green"></h2>
        <h2>I dance <span class="green"></h2>
        <h2>I do silly things <span class="green"></h2>
        <h2>I explore <span class="green"></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>lorem ipsum (changed as text is wordy)</p>
         <p>lorem ipsum (changed as text is wordy)</p>
         <p>lorem ipsum (changed as text is wordy)</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think she's trying to comment out her content will look like this on the front end: I create films // and I assume the span that wraps the "//" is used for color or some sort of styling

Comment: Got it. Ok.  I would still try it out at w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a closing div for the "wrapper"? This could be your issue given it's broken HTML

Try using this in your #topwrapper .left { your styling here }

I don't think your CSS is being loaded too? Check the link within the head

Comment: Do you mean the wrapper in my site, or the topwrapper in the code I've supplied here? Both are closed.

Comment: #topwrapper - seems like you're missing your css too?

Comment: The link is there and the file seems to be fine when I navigate to it. No idea why it's not loading.